# How to fit a picture in its figure tag?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, figure

For a project, I need to create the following [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tR46.png). I managed to create it, but I have some problem with my pictures. I can't make them fit inside their respective `figure` tag. Here, I would like the image to re-size itself together when my screen size increase and/or decrease. And to do that, the biggest problem lays in their `width`.

At first, I tried to apply `%` on the `width` of `.activity-picture`, so it could create the responsive design that I wanted, however it doesn't really work since the container size grows at once and the picture appears at full size. I assume there is a conflict with the `flex-basis` of my `.*-activity-card`. Afterwards, I also tried to apply `fit-content`, `max-content` and `min-content`, but I had basically the same results.

Then, I tried to work with the `max-width` of `.activity-picture`. This time, the problem was that my figure container wasn't 'filled' but put aside like illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amywc.png).

I also tried other methods like not putting the article tags and directly applying `flex-basis` and other stylings on the figure tags, but I had the same problems of sizing...

Here is my code:

```css
figure {
  margin: 0px;
}

#activities-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3%;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
}

.activity-picture {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.long-activity-card {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.medium-activity-card {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  flex-basis: 55%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.small-activity-card {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #F2F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.long-activity-card figure {
  height: 90%;
}

.medium-activity-card figure {
  height: 85%;
}

.small-activity-card figure {
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="activities-nav">
  <article class="long-activity-card">
    <figure>
      <img class="activity-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjxgC.jpg">
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="medium-activity-card">
    <figure>
      <img class="activity-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUTh0.jpg">
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="small-activity-card">
    <figure>
      <img class="activity-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJXeq.jpg">
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="long-activity-card">
    <figure>
      <img class="activity-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFKES.jpg">
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="small-activity-card">
    <figure>
      <img class="activity-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1XzJ.jpg">
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="medium-activity-card">
    <figure>
      <img class="activity-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDI4i.jpg">
    </figure>
  </article>

</nav>
```

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me.

**P.S: Only CSS and HTML are allowed for this project.**

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem, and here I suggest you fix this issue in your project by these points...

- Use a proper image resolution best resolution is 1920 x 1080 Because sometimes occurs by the problem with image resolution.
- Another is you can use `object-fit:cover;` for covering your image completely in `<div>`
- Another thing is that you can set the width at 100%... After that, it will set the image width, at the complete image resolution, (The same thing also applies with height) ...
- At last, Use this snippet to make your image completely covered in div...
- `position:relative; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; object-fit:cover; justify-content:center; overflow:hidden;`

Definitely, it will work in your project...